# Adding multiple stack panels through C# code

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, stackpanel

I have a mom with multiple children. Each child has a name already assigned and needs user input for the value.

I am trying to generate a StackPanel with a TextBlock and TextBox for each child through code. The number of children are unknown so I need a loop to create each StackPanel and them to a "mom" StackPanel which is added to a Border control. When I run the code it runs through the loop fine but it does not show anything in the display.

Here is the code:

```
var momStackPanel = new StackPanel() { Orientation = Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Orientation.Vertical};
foreach (ChildItem item in ChildList)
{
    var childItemSP = new StackPanel();childItemSP.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
    TextBlock nameTB = new TextBlock();
    name.Text = item.Name;
    childItemSP.Children.Add(nameTB);
    TextBox valueTB = new TextBox();
    valueTB .Text = item.Value;
    childItemSP.Children.Add(valueTB);
}
BorderSection.Child = momStackPanel;
BorderSection.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible;
```

Here is the XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition  Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition  Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition  Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition  Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock  x:Name="t4"  Text="t4"  Grid.Row="0"/>
    <Border Grid.Row="1"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <StackPanel >
                    <TextBlock x:Name="r1" Text="{Binding r1}"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                    <TextBlock x:Name="r2" Text="r2" Foreground="DarkGray"/>
                </StackPanel>               
    </Border>
    <Border x:Name="BorderSection" Grid.Row="2">            
    </Border>
    <StackPanel x:Name="CommentPanel" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="3" Margin="6,6,6,6">
        <TextBox x:Name="Comment" Text="" MinHeight="100"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
        <Button x:Name="Submit" Content="Submit" Click="Submit_Click_1"/>
        <Button x:Name="Cancel" Content="Cancel" Click="Cancel_Click_1"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Any ideas how to deal with this?

Comment: You don't add `childItemSP` to anything. Of course, it is not displayed.

Answer (score 1):

The [ItemsControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx) control acts like a StackPanel with a variable number of items. You can bind it to an ObservableCollection, so you don't have to mess with the view at all in the code-behind.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="ChildTemplate.xaml"/>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
</ItemsControl>
```

Then you can provide the child's view in a separate file (ChildTemplate.xaml).

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type myNamespace:ChildViewModel}">
    <StackPanel >
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" />
    </StackPanel> 
</DataTemplate>
```

Don't forget you will have to call OnPropertyChanged for the ObservableCollection whenever you change it.

Comment: gosh! Thanks much. such a stupid mistake. Also the template idea is very helpful. I tried to just do a listview in xaml with the textbox in it and it didnt work. not sure if I had a bug in there or if listview doesnt like it.